# MongoDBAuthRepository in ServiceStack throws MissingMethodException (set_DigestHA1Hash)

Tags: mongodb, servicestack

I get MissingMethodException when trying to register a user using ServiceStack.Authentication.MongoDB package:

Method not found: 'Void ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.UserAuth.set_DigestHA1Hash(System.String)'.

Looking into the source code of ServiceStack, I can see the `UserAuth` class has the `DigestHa1Hash` property implemented from IUserAuth. (notice the case change in `HA`)

I am using the latest versions of both NuGet packages, which were published yesterday (it was also failing with earlier versions).

Can anyone please provide a combination of `ServiceStack` and `ServiceStack.Authentication.MongoDB` versions which works?

Thsis is the MongoDB Authentication repository: (https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Authentication.MongoDB)

Comment: I get the same error using 3.9.68

Comment: This should now be fixed in v3.9.69 just deployed.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I can confirm it works with 3.9.69. @mythz Would you mind posting this as answer so that I can mark as answered? Does ServiceStack.Authentication.MongoDB have an issue tracker? The Project Site link links to ServiceStack.OrmLite on github.

Comment: @Marek MongoDB has been merged into the main [ServiceStack repo](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Authentication.MongoDb). An issue tracker will be available for customers after v4 beta is released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved in v3.9.69 release of ServiceStack that was recently deployed.